# Can't draw in title bar on WM_NCPAINT?

Tags: winapi, gdi

I'm trying to draw something in the title bar area to represent an X since there is no `WS_CAPTION`, it just uses `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST` and `WS_POPUP|WS_THICKFRAME`.  But I can't get anything to draw anywhere.  I did a test below to just fill it all in red, but nothing changed.  What am I doing wrong or missing?

```
case WM_NCACTIVATE:
case WM_NCPAINT:
{
  // call default handler (I've tried it both ways, with and without DefWindowProc)
  ::DefWindowProc(hwnd, umsg, wparam, lparam);
  HDC hdc;
  if ((hdc=::GetWindowDC(hwnd))!=NULL) { 
    // Paint into this DC 
    RECT rcwin;
    if (::GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rcwin)) {
      HBRUSH hbrush=::CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
      if (hbrush) {
        rcwin.right-=rcwin.left;
        rcwin.bottom-=rcwin.top;
        rcwin.left=rcwin.top=0;
        ::FillRect(hdc, &rcwin, hbrush);
        ::DeleteObject(hbrush);
      }
    }
    ::ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [How to correctly draw simple non-client area (4 px red border)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132757/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a Link from Remy about the evil WM_NCPAINT, converted from the pascal version to the C++ version below.  It works as well as the link in stackoverflow but again, only if `WS_CAPTION` is provided.  I'm just posting here for completeness.

```
case WM_NCPAINT:
{
    #ifndef DCX_USESTYLE
      #define DCX_USESTYLE 0x00010000
    #endif

  HDC hdc=::GetDCEx(hwnd, 0, DCX_WINDOW|DCX_USESTYLE);
  if (hdc) {
    RECT rcclient;
    ::GetClientRect(hwnd, &rcclient);
    RECT rcwin;
    ::GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rcwin);
    POINT ptupleft;
    ptupleft.x=rcwin.left;
    ptupleft.y=rcwin.top;
    ::MapWindowPoints(0, hwnd, (LPPOINT) &rcwin, (sizeof(RECT)/sizeof(POINT)));
    ::OffsetRect(&rcclient, -rcwin.left, -rcwin.top);
    ::OffsetRect(&rcwin, -rcwin.left, -rcwin.top);

    HRGN rgntemp=NULL;
    if (wparam==NULLREGION || wparam==ERROR) {
      ::ExcludeClipRect(hdc, rcclient.left, rcclient.top, rcclient.right, rcclient.bottom);
    }
    else {
      rgntemp=::CreateRectRgn(rcclient.left+ptupleft.x, rcclient.top+ptupleft.y, rcclient.right+ptupleft.x, rcclient.bottom+ptupleft.y);
      if (::CombineRgn(rgntemp, (HRGN) wparam, rgntemp, RGN_DIFF)==NULLREGION) {
         // nothing to paint
      }
      ::OffsetRgn(rgntemp, -ptupleft.x, -ptupleft.y);
      ::ExtSelectClipRgn(hdc, rgntemp, RGN_AND);
    }

    HBRUSH hbrush = ::CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
    ::FillRect(hdc, &rcwin, hbrush);
    ::DeleteObject(hbrush);

    ::ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
    if (rgntemp!=0) {
      ::DeleteObject(rgntemp);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the code does not work without `WS_CAPTION` style? If you `remove WS_CAPTION`, what will happen?

Comment: Well with one of the examples, not this latest one, the client area is a gradient so the red flashed or I could pause in debug mode and see the red in that area.   With the `WS_CAPTION` you see the title bar and frame around it red.   But without that, you just have the client area and a small white titlebar that is about 1/4 or so of a normal titlebar but I can't write on that, it's always just a white extra thick line.

Comment: All right. Do not forget to mark your own answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Do not draw directly in `WM_NCACTIVATE`.  If you need to trigger a repaint, you can use [`RedrawWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-redrawwindow) for that.  Do all of the actual drawing in `WM_PAINT`/`WM_NCPAINT`.

When drawing in `WM_NCPAINT`, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-ncpaint) says to use [`GetDCEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdcex) to get the `HDC` to draw on. The `wParam` is an `HRGN` that you can draw within. You can use [`GetRgnBox()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getrgnbox) to get the bounding rectangle of the `HRGN`, if needed.

```cpp
case WM_NCPAINT: {
    ::DefWindowProc(hwnd, umsg, wparam, lparam);
    HRGN hrgn = (HRGN)wParam;
    HDC hdc = ::GetDCEx(hwnd, hrgn, DCX_WINDOW | DCX_INTERSECTRGN);
    HBRUSH hbrush = ::CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
    ::FillRgn(hdc, hrgn, hbrush);
    ::DeleteObject(hbrush);
    ::ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that using the example in the MSDN docs (same as what you are using above), the GetDCEx() always returns NULL.  That's where I found others had the same problem and used GetWindowDC() instead.

Comment: @df234987 see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50135792/65863) to [How to correctly draw simple non-client area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132757/).  Apparently I forgot that there are undocumented gotchas with `WM_NCPAINT`

Comment: **Do not draw directly in WM_NCACTIVATE**. @RemyLebeau you are wrong. Look at the Windows classic theme: system buttons and caption are drawn **exactly** in `WM_NCACTIVATE` when main window becomes active or inactive. Not in `WM_NCPAINT`! Also if you click on HELP system button and then click anywhere in the window then close button and help button will be redrawn not on `WM_NCACTIVATE`, not on `WM_NCPAINT` and even not in `WM_PAINT`. They will be redrawn somewhere else. This is according to my non-client drawings research.