# is it safe to store the calculated RECT from a WM_NCCALCSIZE in a class member RECT variable and use it later in WM_NCPAINT?

Tags: windows, winapi, rect

I need to know if it is safe to store some calculated non-client area RECT (not the window rect neither the client one, it is a based on some calculation) from the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message and use it later in the `WM_NCPAINT` without the need to do the whole recalculation process again in `WM_NCPAINT`!?

i.e. is `WM_NCPAINT` always called immediately after `WM_NCCALCSIZE`?

I need to save the hassle of doing the recalculation process in `WM_NCPAINT` message, because `DefWindowProc` from `WM_NCCALCSIZE` already does all what I need to start my calculations based on what it does.

TIA.

Comment: I don't think you could guarantee it. Why not move your calculations to a function, then you can call it from both places.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I read the question as being an issue with the *performance* of doing the same calculation multiple times. So moving the calculation to a function for both messages to call won't solve that.

Comment: I have not tested this, but it seems logical that the non-client area would have to be sized before it can be painted, so it would make sense for `WM_NCCALCSIZE` to always precede `WM_NCPAINT`. Should be easy to verify with some test code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i.e. is `WM_NCPAINT` always called immediately after `WM_NCCALCSIZE`?

I test this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50135792/11128312) which provided by krsi, we can find that `WM_NCCALCSIZE` is always called before `WM_NCPAINT`, but this does not mean that no other messages were called in the middle. For example, when testing, after receiving `WM_NCCALCSIZE`, `WM_PAINT` will be called first, and then `WM_NCPAINT` will be called.

You seem to be customizing the non-client area, I think you can first read [Nonclient Area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/nonclient-area).

> In general, processing these messages for standard windows is not
> recommended, because the application must be able to draw all the
> required parts of the nonclient area for the window. For this reason,
> most applications pass these messages to DefWindowProc for default
> processing.
>
> An application that creates custom nonclient areas for its windows
> must process these messages. When doing so, the application must use a
> window device context to carry out drawing in the window. The window
> device context enables the application to draw in all portions of the
> window, including the nonclient area. An application retrieves a
> window device context by using the GetWindowDC or GetDCEx function
> and, when drawing is complete, must release the window device context
> by using the ReleaseDC function.

If you just consider whether the size of the custom client area will change when `WM_NCPAINT` is called, I can't give a suitable answer because I haven't seen your code and I don't know what kind of project you need to complete.

I just tested the sample in another link, the non-client area will always maintain the border size of 4pixel, and the calculation is also performed in `WM_NCCALCSIZE`.