# How are custom Windows Borders and styles done?

Tags: windows, border, customization

I have seen a program recently that has got what appears to be a custom Window border.
I don't know how this is accomplished. If anyone does know then please do tell me as this is interesting.
I am mostly interested in something similar shown in the picture

[Window example of what I am trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Xmb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must [handle the non-client messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50135792/3501) like `WM_NCPAINT`. Depending on your design you might need to call `DwmDefWindowProc` as well.

Use `SetWindowRgn` if you want XP style rounded edges or `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` for full alpha support and custom shadows.